# ReactJS - React.Children.forEach - Can I get the child component name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React (15.5.4) component with many children, some of which are HTML elements and some are other React components.

I'm using server rendering and need the same behavior on the server and client. The client will be using the production build of React.

I need to iterate over the children and identify a specific type of React component. So my first thought was to iterate using `React.Children.forEach()` and look for the component name.

```
React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
  console.log('name =', child.name)
})
```

It seems `child.name` and `child.displayName` don't exist.

Now, `child.type` exists, and is either a string (for HTML elements) like `"ul"` or a function (for React components).

When it's a function, I can use `lodash/get` like this `const type = get(child, 'type.name', '')` to get the component name. **However**, this only seems to work on the server, not in the client side production build, where it returns a string: `"t"`. It looks like the development build uses my component name for the function, but the production build renames it to `t()`. So I can't use `child.type.name`.

How do I:

1. Iterate over a components children and identify a specific type of component..?
2. Which works in both the development and production React builds..?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can set the component's name in the property `displayName`. If you're using ES6 classes, you can set a static property called `displayName` into component's class. Then, you'll be able to get the child name with `child.type.displayName`.

```js
const FirstChild = ({ name }) => <li>{name}</li>;
FirstChild.displayName = 'FirstChild';

const SecondChild = ({ name }) => <li>{name}</li>;
SecondChild.displayName = 'SecondChild';

class ThirdChild extends React.Component {
  static displayName = 'ThirdChild';
  
  render() {
    return (
      <li>{this.props.name}</li>
    );
  }
  
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
      console.log('name =', child.type.displayName);
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>{this.props.children}</ul>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Parent>
        <FirstChild name='1st child value' />
        <SecondChild name='2nd child value' />
        <ThirdChild name='3rd child value' />
      </Parent>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something already set on the components, but using `FirstChild.displayName = 'FirstChild'` to set my own static property works very well.

Comment: Thanks! Glad to help.

Comment: Is there an explanation as to why a deployed build returns 't'?

Comment: @deanmau5 returns 't'? where? =/

Comment: Taken from the author's question : "However, this only seems to work on the server, not in the client side production build, where it returns a string: "t". It looks like the development build uses my component name for the function, but the production build renames it to t(). So I can't use child.type.name."

Comment: oh, yes, I'm sorry! The author's question!!! =D
answering your question: I would have to investigate a bit more by trying to reproduce the issue on my env. That's why I came up with an alternative solution ;)

Comment: no problem!  I've encountered the same but had no explanation as to why it happened.  Your answer does work however.

Comment: How do you get the `static displayName = 'ThirdChild';` to work? It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Babel, you can use this Babel plugin to automatically set the `displayName`, so that `child.type.displayName` will equal the string of whatever you've named the component:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-react-displayname

It's easy to install and use, just read the directions and make sure to add the plugin name `add-react-displayname` to your plugins array in your `.babelrc` file.