# react-native: Creating components like <group> <item /> <Item /> .. </group>

Tags: react-native, tabs, components, parent-child

Im a old C++ developper and, now, starting in react-native and javascript.

I want a create something like a TabLayout (Android) but to work in react-native.

My idea is use 2 compoments: 1 parent (to control) and many children (using one child class ).

```
<Parent>
  <Child />
  <Child />
  ...
</Parent>
```

The parent need identify how much child, show a child list in top or bottom (like a tablayout), control the child active and call active child render.

I see samething using React (using this.props.children()) but I tryed in react-native and dont work.

Please, anyone can help me (or indicate where I can find a help or sample) ?

Comment: https://github.com/paraswatts/DrawerNavigatorReactNative. User this sample project I made this using drawer , stack and tab navigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react-native you can use `this.props.children` like you do in react. From your question, I can understand that you used it as it is a function but it is not. Below is a simple example of how you can use it. ([*Working snack*](https://snack.expo.io/SyOjkQL5M))

For more detail you can check [this article](https://mxstbr.blog/2017/02/react-children-deepdive/) from [Max Stoiber](https://github.com/mxstbr).

> Because we’re working with JavaScript, we can change children. We can
>   send special properties to them, decide if we want them to render or
>   not and generally manipulate them to our will.

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => {
  return (<View style={props.style || {}}>{props.children}</View>)
};

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  return (<Text style={props.style || {}}>{props.name}</Text>)
}

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ParentComponent style={styles.container}>
        {
          [0,1,2,3,4,5].map((item) => (<ChildComponent style={styles.paragraph} name={`Child Component ${item + 1}`} />))
        }
      </ParentComponent>
    );
  }
}
```

Although creating a challenging component is a good practice and an exercise it is kinda unnecessary to invent the wheel again for a project. Unless you have a special requirement that no current well maintain library can solve, you don't have to do it yourself. There is a lot of good libraries for navigation and TabView. You can find most of them from [`awesome-react-native`](https://github.com/jondot/awesome-react-native)

Comment: I agree in parts. I have not found a component that does exactly what I would like.
I would like a component that allows me to create a TabLayout that I can show in on top or at the bottom and can be used without affecting existing components. This tab will show 3 lists: students, classes and exams (selectable through the tab).
The number of Tab elements may be larger than this, and I would like to be able to put a paging (or scrolling) if I can.
I would like to be able to place icons instead of texts (especially if it is below).
That is, I have several ideas and I would use this to learn.

Comment: In IOS work fine but in Android I received a message: "cannot add a child that doesn't have a yoganode ..."

Comment: How do I only treat the tag I defined as a child?
Better, how do I know what the child's tag is?

Comment: @CelsoCruz you can check the displayName of the child like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43914310)

Comment: I see the Max Stoiber's article (and I liked very much)  but dont work in my tests using react-native... Maybe work in React for Web...

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [react-navigation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html#react-navigation)

You can add a header at the top which and evenly distribute your buttons there and then append a component that extends StackNavigator below it (don't forget to disable a header in screens).

This will also provide an ability to use fade/scroll animations on your screens.
For the main header, you can add some [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html) or [Interactable](https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable) line to highlight an active screen.

Comment: Im trying learn react-native too. And, I think, its a good chalenge to understand some questions...