# ReactDOM.findDOMNode() using React.Children child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm trying to access a component's specific child DOM node like this:

```
let targetChild = null;
React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
    if (child.type.displayName === 'TargetElement') {
        targetChild = child;
    }
});

const targetEl = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(targetChild);
```

However, I keep getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: Argument appears to not be a ReactComponent.

When I log out the `typeof targetChild` I get `object`. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You could set up a component called `TargetElement` and assign the props to it from `child` directly. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913054/reactjs-react-children-foreach-can-i-get-the-child-component-name)

Comment: Alternatively you could also use [`React.cloneElement()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to clone your target element. Do keep in minfd that the new clone will have the same `ref` as the original target element.

Comment: Can you include code of the parent and children components?

Comment: Can you share the complete component code in which you are trying to get the DOM node? Thanks

Comment: @MarksCode I'm curious, what are you trying to achieve? `findDOMNode` [is discouraged](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) so maybe there is another way to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: @MarksCode are you doing this in render method?

Comment: As bamse said it is discouraged to use findDOMNode, So why can't you use React refs as React official docs said?

Comment: @MarksCode note that `typeof null` is `object` updated in answer as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Above all `findDOMNode` should not be used**

**Also note that `typeof null` is `object`**

**The problem is you are passing the `React Element` instead of `React Component's instance`**

read more about difference between `React Element` vs `React Component` vs `React Component instance` https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html

in short if `UL` is a `React Component` ( either class component or function component ) then `<UL />` is `React element`

**Also note that you can use `findDOMNode` only on `Class Component` not the function component**

The documentation seems a little misleading because it says

> ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component)

notice it says `Component` but I did some search and find out that you need to pass the `component's instance` instead of component

for example following will work because `this` will points to the component's instance

```
import React  from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const UL = props => {
  return <ul>{props.children}</ul>;
};

class List extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('printing', ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
  }
  render() {
    return <li>this is targe element</li>;
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UL>
        <li>Hello CodeSandbox</li>
        <List />
        <li>Start editing to see some magic happen!</li>
      </UL>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

but following will not work because we are passing a `React element` instead of component's instance

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class UL extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let element = null;
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (child, index) => {
      if (index === 1) {
        console.log('logging child', child);
        element = child;
      }
    });
    console.log('printing', ReactDOM.findDOMNode(element));
  }
  render() {
    return <ul>{this.props.children}</ul>;
  }
};

class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <li>this is targe element</li>;
  }
}

List.displayName = 'TargetElement';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UL>
        <li>Hello CodeSandbox</li>
        <List />
        <li>Start editing to see some magic happen!</li>
      </UL>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the DOM element of a particular React component instance, you need to use the [**Callback Refs**](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

Here's a demo for you:

```js
const children = ['Bob', 'Jeff', 'Kate'];
const TARGET_NODE = 'Jeff';
let jeffRef;

const setRef = (el, label) => {
 if(label === TARGET_NODE) {
  jeffRef = el;
 }
}

const SampleApp = ({children}) => (
 <ul>
   {children.map((child, index) => (
      <li key={index} ref={el => setRef(el, child)}>{child}</li>
 ))}
 </ul>
)

ReactDOM.render(<SampleApp children={children}/>, document.querySelector("#app"))

console.log(jeffRef) // Should output: <li>Jeff</li>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

*PS: In my opinion, accessing DOM elements can be avoided in most cases. You might want to reconsider doing that. You can control/update the element using component state instead.*